# How to determine if a color is close to another color

Tags: c#, system.drawing.color

I am creating a kind of color tool and this tool should tell me if color is close to another color,
For example:

```
Color[] colors = new colors[] { Color.FromArgb(0,0,255), Color.FromArgb(0,109,251)};
//colors[0] IS BLUE
//colors[1] IS BRIGHTER BLUE (#006DFB)
bool TheyClose = ColorsAreClose(colors[0],colors[1]); //TRUE BLUE IS CLOSE
//TheyColse Should Be = TURE
```

How should a `ColorsAreClose()` function Look?

Comment: How do you define "close"?

Comment: Look up [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and find if the are similar in hue, brightness and saturation.

Comment: What do you consider close colors?

Comment: Seeing all the (accepted) answers, I felt a comment was more helpful.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference is the article about colour difference.  Using CIELAB and the differences there, comes up with a more human-perception measure of difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
bool ColorsAreClose(Color a, Color z, int threshold = 50)
{
    int r = (int)a.R - z.R,
        g = (int)a.G - z.G,
        b = (int)a.B - z.B;
    return (r*r + g*g + b*b) <= threshold*threshold;
}
```

(I just guessed at the default threshold, but you should set it to what you want.)

Basically this just computes, on average, whether the three color channels are close enough between the two colors.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way, measure RGB distance:

```
public bool ColorsAreClose(Color[] colors)
{

    var rDist = Math.Abs(colors[0].R - colors[1].R);
    var gDist = Math.Abs(colors[0].G - colors[1].G);
    var bDist = Math.Abs(colors[0].B - colors[1].B);

    if(rDist + gDist + bDist > Threshold)
        return false;

    return true;

}
```

Threshold is a constant with the maximum deviation you want to consider close.

Comment: Thank You :) i also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846286/c-sharp-finding-similar-colors

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate  the 3-D color space distance as

```
Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(c1.R-c2.R,2)+Math.Pow(c1.G-c2.g,2)+Math.Pow(c1.B-c2.b,2)));
```

or you can calculate the hue difference as

```
Math.Abs(c1.GetHue() - c2.GetHue());
```

A more thorough discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621#27375621).

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat subjective and not scientific, I used the following procedure on a project once.

```
public bool IsMatch(Color colorA, Color colorB)
{
    return IsMatch(colorA.Red, colorB.Red)
        && IsMatch(colorA.Green, colorB.Green)
        && IsMatch(colorA.Blue, colorB.Blue);
}

public bool IsMatch(double colorA, double colorB)
{
    var difference = colorA - colorB;
    return -5 < difference
        || difference < 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If talking just about hue you could compare the difference in RGB values separately and if the total difference is under a set amount set by you then you could call them close.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
double delta = Math.Abs(c1.GetHue() - c2.GetHue());
if(delta > 180)
  delta = 360 - delta;
return delta <= threshold
```

For more info about the hue see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue