# Efficient way to detect similar color

Tags: c++, colors

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to detect similar colors?

I've been trying to find solutions, and the best "solution" I have found is this StackOverflow question:

[How to determine if a color is close to another color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168445/)

But, It seems to be detecting black more than the color I assigned, also with the threshold on low.

Here is my code:

```
COLORREF color_yellow = (255, 255, 0);
COLORREF color;

bool ColorsAreClose(COLORREF Colora, COLORREF Colorz, int threshold = 70)
{
    int r = (int)GetRValue(Colora) - GetRValue(Colorz),
        g = (int)GetGValue(Colora) - GetGValue(Colorz),
        b = (int)GetBValue(Colora) - GetBValue(Colorz);
    return (r * r + g * g + b * b) <= threshold * threshold;
}

int main(){
    while (true) {
        if (ColorsAreClose(color, color_yellow) == true) {
            std::cout << "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It mostly always detects black colors alot more than yellow. (Just to clarify what my issue is.) and for anyone wondering, I am getting my main color from get pixel.

Comment: Edit the question if you want to clarify something

Comment: I am here not very clear what you mean by your "efficient way" and "best 'solution'".

Comment: Please specify your inputs, your expected outputs, and your actual outputs.

Comment: `COLORREF` is just a plain integer, a typedef for `DWORD`. `COLORREF color_yellow = (255, 255, 0);` is equivalent to `COLORREF color_yellow = 0;` (read about comma operator in your favorite C++ textbook). Your `color_yellow` is in fact black. You are looking for [`RGB` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb), as in `COLORREF color_yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`COLORREF color_yellow = (255, 255, 0);` is equivalent to `COLORREF color_yellow = 0;`. The expression `(255, 255, 0)` involves the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) and evaluates to 0. Thus, `color_yellow` ends up representing black color, not yellow color.

To construct a `COLORREF` value from three color components, use [`RGB` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb):

```
COLORREF color_yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0);
```