# Compare colors with toleration

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, bitmap

Today I am trying to check if one color is similar to another in CSharp from BitMap. This is code, what I am using:

```
Color blah = screenshot.GetPixel(x, y);
if (blah == Color.Red) {
...
```

The problem is, that I never get `true`, because the color has a little bit different shade. Is there any way to compare this colors with some tolerance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may check defince a tolarance value and check if their difference is less than that:

```
Color blah = screenshot.GetPixel(x, y);
    if (Math.Abs(Color.Red.GetHue() - blah.GetHue()) <= tolorance)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a better solution:

```
 public bool AreColorsSimilar(Color c1, Color c2, int tolerance)
 {
     return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) < tolerance &&
            Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) < tolerance &&
            Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) < tolerance;
 }
```

---

Source:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846345/5364144

Comment: This is great, except I got an arithmetic exception when I used it.  Needed to tweak it (in vb.net) to:  Return (Math.Abs(CInt(c1.R) - CInt(c2.R)) < tolerance) AndAlso (Math.Abs(CInt(c1.G) - CInt(c2.G)) < tolerance) AndAlso (Math.Abs(CInt(c1.B) - CInt(c2.B)) < tolerance)