# Get difference between two colors in the color wheel java

Tags: java, android, colors, palette

I have an android app that I want to tell me if two colors match. And I know matching is done by using their distance in the color wheel. how do I get the distance between two of them so I can tell if they match or not

Answer (score 0):

From [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262258/how-could-i-compare-colors-in-java), you can tell if 2 colors match using something like this:

```
   boolean sameColor(Color c1, Color c2){
        double distance = (c1.r - c2.r)*(c1.r - c2.r) + (c1.g - c2.g)*(c1.g - c2.g) + (c1.b - c2.b)*(c1.b - c2.b)

        if (distance == 0){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Alternatively, if you want to check if the 2 colors are within some tolerance of eachother, you could try something like this instead:

```
   boolean sameColor(Color c1, Color c2){
        double distance = (c1.r - c2.r)*(c1.r - c2.r) + (c1.g - c2.g)*(c1.g - c2.g) + (c1.b - c2.b)*(c1.b - c2.b)

        if (distance > tolerance){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But by "match" you mean?

Comment: match meaning that the difference between the 2 colors is 0