# Delphi - image colors detection

Tags: delphi, colors, rgb, timage

i have a question, is there some library, or piece of code that can detect if color is most similar to greeen, blue, yellow or so?

i can decompose the pixel color of TImage with this function:

```
procedure RGB(Col: TColor; var R, G, B: Byte);
var
  Color: $0..$FFFFFFFF;
begin
  Color := ColorToRGB(Col);
  R := ($000000FF and Color);
  G := ($0000FF00 and Color) Shr 8;
  B := ($00FF0000 and Color) Shr 16;
end;
```

but with simply comparation of r>g>b  i cannot determine, if the color is more similar to yellow, brown or so. I need only few basic colors (working on little kids education stuff)

I will be very thankfull for every hint, or help.

Comment: The definition of 'similar' is a bit tricky. You could do something that finds the difference for each of red, green and blue and chooses the lowest difference. Here is a suggestion for javascript, which you could adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725505/finding-similar-colors-programatically

Comment: I tried to define  "collor difference" ranges, but without success.. i just need to detrmine basic colors (red green blue yellow black white brown)  for kids in the kindergarden - they will touch the screen and the app will tell the color via speakers..