# Database design to store image color pattern in MySQL for searching Image by color

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, search

I am building a image galley using PHP and MySQL where I want to implement **Image search by it's color**. By following [Imagick::getImageHistogram](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagehistogram.php) i got the most presented colors from the images.

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick("thing.png");
$pixels=$image->getImageHistogram();
foreach($pixels as $p){
 $colors = $p->getColor();
 foreach($colors as $c){
        print( "$c\t" );
 }
 print( "\t:\t" . $p->getColorCount() . "\n" );
}
?>

This will print out something like:

Red    Green    Blue       Alpha    :    No of times appeared
252    250      252        1        :       125
194    156      182        1        :       126
109    18       79         1        :       11440
2      117      162        1        :       12761
255    255      255        1        :       40769
```

Although I am done with getting the colors, I am stuck with designing the database to store the color information along with image path in the database.

My question is how to design a database (table structure) to store this kind of data where search can query can be applied in an effective manner.

**Update:**

Secondly how can I get the images with a matching color. Let's say user is searching for a color #ff0000, then how can I get all the nearest matched images from the database.

Thank You

Comment: What do you have so far? This data looks nice and regular so it should be fairly straightforward, right?

Comment: What would a potential query look like?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Let's say I am storing 6 colors for a image that means we are having overall 18 values(6 * (R, B, G)) values. So how to can design the table to store these values

Answer (score 3):

You should normalize this.

3 Tables:

```
Image {image_id, name}
Colors {color_id, red, green, blue, alpha}
ImageHasColor {image_id, color_id, number_of_times_appeared}
```

Inserting data should be simple, use `...insert_id` functions to get the id from the row you just inserted.

Select with joins like:

```
SELECT * FROM
Image i
JOIN ImageHasColors h
ON i.image_id = h.image_id
JOIN Colors c
ON c.color_id = h.color_id
ORDER BY i.image_id
```

Check this link on how to convert HEX color to RGB values: http://bavotasan.com/2011/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-using-php/

Search top 10 really red pictures:

```
SELECT * FROM
Image i
JOIN ImageHasColors h
ON i.image_id = h.image_id
JOIN Colors c
ON c.color_id = h.color_id
WHERE c.red > 200
AND   c.green < 50
AND   c. green < 50
ORDER BY h.number_of_times_appeared
LIMIT 10
```

Search rather black pictures:

```
SELECT * FROM
Image i
JOIN ImageHasColors h
ON i.image_id = h.image_id
JOIN Colors c
ON c.color_id = h.color_id
WHERE c.red < 30
AND   c.green < 30
AND   c. green < 30
ORDER BY h.number_of_times_appeared
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank You. How can i get all the images by passing a color. Let's say I am searching for red #ff0000 how can i get nearest matching of all the images?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a database table with the following fields:

Images Table

```
id
name
red
green
blue
alpha
```

Comment: Fine, but this is store one color along with the image. What about other color ?

Comment: Hi there, what other color? RGB values create pretty much every color in the visible light spectrum... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

Comment: Read the question... his output is: top most colors appearing in 1 image (color #123456 appears 100 times, color #444444 appears 50 times,. ....)

Answer (score 0):

How about you first times all the red values by the number of times they appeared and then add those values together to get the overall red value. Then divide by the total number of times appeared. Do the same for Green and Blue.

For example:

```
total red = ((252*125)+(194*126)+(109*11440)+(2*12761)+(255*40769)) 
            / (125 + 126 + 11440 + 12761 + 40769)
          = 180
```

Then just store them in the database like

```
             id         red      green       blue     image_path
Image 1      1          225      134         4        /dir/
Image 2      2          143      0           145      /dir/
Image 3      3          239      200         111      /dir/
```

If you were searching for Red images you could do something like:

```
SELECT id, image_path WHERE red > 200 AND blue < 100 AND green < 100
```

Im not sure of the specifics, but you could mess around with the values.