# how to get similar color images from database [php]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using [brianmcdo ImagePalette](https://github.com/brianmcdo/ImagePalette) to get color Palette

and i want to find similar images to one image w.r.t color/color range.

here is my code

```
<?php 
require_once $config->root.'/script/vendor/image-palette/vendor/autoload.php';
// initiate with image
$palette = new \BrianMcdo\ImagePalette\ImagePalette( 'http://i.imgur.com/GL7igry.png' );

// get the prominent colors
$colors = $palette->colors; // array of Color objects

//storing in databse
?>
```

Now i Need a perfect SQL To return similar rows From Database Having Same Or Matching Color Palette Code [Values Are stored Like Ex: #000000,#999999,#333399] And Also one different table w.r.t image id for fast indexing?

if it's a duplicate question just give me the link i will delete the question iam getting a lot of downvotes and i dont know where to ask else

Comment: what is the structure of your DB?

Comment: 3 cols in color_image table - id[auto increnement] img_id[image id] color_code[#ffff]

Comment: and one main table where i stored all colors in one col like ex- #fff,#eee,#ddd

Comment: what is the RDBMS used? MySQL? MSSQL? Other? The question is  unclear.

Comment: i m using mysql pdo

Comment: When posting a question and a database is involved, you need to add as much information as possible, including using the proper tags. This could have an effect on answers given. I added the "mysql" tag but left out the one for "pdo". I probably should have added it, but that could be irrelevant. If people submit answers with `mysql_` or `mysqli_` answers, then you'll need to edit your tags and the question to hold the related code for it.

Comment: okae i will do it next time

Comment: What do you define as "similar" wrt colours?

Comment: [example what i want](https://wall.alphacoders.com/by_color.php?hex_color=b36363)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024769/database-design-to-store-image-color-pattern-in-mysql-for-searching-image-by-col

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can build the SQL string for the query. You should be using prepared statements, so translate this to whatever library you are using, but this code will give you the sql query.

```
if($colors != null && count($colors) > 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM color_image WHERE";

    foreach($colors as $color)
    {
        $sql .= " color_code = '". $color . "' OR ";
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql, " OR ");
}
```

Comment: but it will only return exact same code image. i also need similar images to that color

Comment: This is impossible as there is no DB that i am aware of that has anything built in to handle hex colors. You will need to pull the entire DB and use php to do this. You have not provided enough info in your question for me to help you any further than what i have written already

Comment: You don't build queries by jamming together arbitrary strings. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. There's also no need for a string of `OR` clauses. Just use `WHERE IN (?,?,?,...)` with the `?` part repeated as necessary.

Comment: @tadman i clearly stated in my answer that this was just to explain how the idea works and said that the OP should use prepared statements. Since he did not specify what library he was using, i wasnt going to go and write the entire application for him

Comment: What you say doesn't always get noticed when what you do is ignore your own advice. Also the least you can do is use `implode` to avoid the `rtrim` mess at the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024769/database-design-to-store-image-color-pattern-in-mysql-for-searching-image-by-col this is what i am asking