# Finding Similar HEX colors using a threshold

Tags: php, javascript, image-processing

I have an array of RGB hex colors.
I would like to find a quick and dirty way to group them by color similarity and threshold value.

spec: [image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization . Or you could try fiddling with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php

Comment: I would suggest yoo use a HSV model so you can compare Hue, Saturation, and Value among several colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
$dr = $red1   - $red2;
$dg = $green1 - $green2;
$db = $blue1  - $blue2;
$fr = 2; // may be adjusted
$fg = 4; // "
$fb = 1; // "
$distance_squared = $fr * $dr * $dr + $fg * $dg * $dg + $fb * $db * $db;
```

You would then compare `$distance_squared` to the square of the threshold. The factors may be adjusted (especially blue might get a higher factor), as well as their sum (in order to match the threshold)

For a "slow and clean" solution, I would start from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) (and [here](http://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm) for a more practical approach).

Answer (score 1):

Choose a [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses), and define "similarity" as e.g. Euclidean distance between the coordinates of the two colours.  HSL/HSV might be a better choice than RGB, for instance.

Comment: yep i figured that much too. 
just looking for a formula if anyone has one handy ;-)

Comment: @Artur: A formula for what?  Conversion formulae to e.g. HSV are given  in the Wikipedia article.  Euclidean distance is simply sqrt((a1-a2)^2 + (b1-b2)^2 + (c1-c2)^2).

Comment: thanks - I also found this helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633828/distance-between-colours-in-php/1634206#1634206